# Combine two string objects in attribute to use in .map loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am combining PHP objects into strings, which gives me this result here:

```
{"icon":"dark-mode","classes":"dark-mode","local":"test1"}
{"icon":"settings","classes":"settings","local":"test2"}
```

How can I convert this string into an array so I can map it with the .map function?

Comment: is this array of objects, your result? and whats the expected output?

Comment: Call `JSON.parse()` on each string, and push them onto an array.

Comment: I suggest you fix the PHP so it creates the JSON array in the first place.

Comment: `const obj = JSON.parse(str) Object.values(obj).map(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your example describes two JavaScript objects, so not sure, what you were exactly asking for.

One of these approaches?

```js
var line1 = {
  "icon": "dark-mode",
  "classes": "dark-mode",
  "local": "test1"
};
var line2 = {
  "icon": "settings",
  "classes": "settings",
  "local": "test2"
};

var combined = {};
Object.keys(line1).forEach(function(key) {
  if (combined[key]) {
    combined[key].push(line1[key]);
  } else {
    combined[key] = [line1[key]]
  }
});

Object.keys(line2).forEach(function(key) {
  if (combined[key]) {
    combined[key].push(line2[key]);
  } else {
    combined[key] = [line2[key]]
  }
});

console.log(combined);
console.log([line1, line2]);
```

If not, could you describe the target structure?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Object.keys(youObj)**  to convert keys of object and use it for map

```js
const someObj = {"icon":"dark-mode","classes":"dark-mode","local":"test1"}

const objToString = Object.keys(someObj).map(item => `key = ${item}, item = ${someObj[item]}`)

console.log(objToString)
```